# How to create xsd which can preserve formatted text?

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to create XML Schema which can preserve formatted text Like,
Line break , extra space ...

Comment: i have figured it out and got the ans Here is the link
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665542/how-to-create-xsd-which-can-preserve-space-in-xml/8665583#8665583)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean you wannt to create xml schema that can preserve the space in xml , If that is the question then here is the ans below

The element which you want to preserve the space just create your own data type for that element. For Ex:-

```
 <xs:simpleType name="TitleString"> 
   <xs:restriction base="xs:string"> 
     <xs:whiteSpace value="preserve"/> 
       <xs:minLength value="5"/> 
       <xs:maxLength value="230"/> 
   </xs:restriction> 
 </xs:simpleType>
```

and use this type in your element . tell me if you find any prob.