# How to create xsd which can preserve space in xml?

Tags: xml, xsd

how can I create XML Schema which can preserve space in the xml ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean you wannt to create xml schema that can preserve the space in xml ,
If that is the question then here is the ans below

The element which you want to preserve the space just create your own data type for that element.
For Ex:-

```
 <xs:simpleType name="TitleString">
   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
     <xs:whiteSpace value="preserve"/>
       <xs:minLength value="5"/>
       <xs:maxLength value="230"/>
   </xs:restriction>
 </xs:simpleType>
```

and use this type in your element .
tell me if you find any prob.

Comment: I am just checking and let you know